# Copy directory across domains using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to copy a directory from a PC in one domain to another using a batch file. I have used below **net use** command but it gives me an error saying 
"System error 53 has occured. The network path is not found".

```
@echo off

net use Z: "\\serverIP\SharedFolderName\" /user:domain2\testuser 
xcopy "C:\Teset" "Z:\"

net use Z: /delete
```

Am I missing something ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the trailing `\` in `"\\serverIP\SharedFolderName\"`.

Comment: Hi, I have removed the trailing slash from the command and now i'm getting a different error "System error 1219 has occurred. Multiple connections to a server or a shared resource by the same user, using more than one user, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again."    Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @Rajesh: It could possibly have something to do with your attempt to connect to that resource while having already been connected to it. Could it be that your system establishes a connection to that resource with every startup? Anyway, that's a completely different problem. You might want to post a new question about it.